# Maximum number of characters in a syllable block

Tags: hangul

I've seen a number of Hangul syllables that contain 4 characters (닭, for example) - is it possible to have syllables with 5 (or even more) characters in them? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#Letter_placement_within_a_block) on Hangul suggests it's possible, but doesn't give an example - and I can't find other resources to say for sure either way.

Comment: Interesting question... are you looking for examples from real words in particular? (I can certainly type '봙' in my IME...)

Comment: Well, there's 뷁, which is an internet slang meaning WTF (it came from some singer's rather over-enthusiastic pronunciation of the English word "break").  But I can't think of a legitimate(?) Korean word with 5 jamo's.

Comment: @topo-morto yeah, ideally looking for a real-world answer (just because an IME will let you doesn't necessarily mean it's possible in the language). Thanks for the slang answer, @jick!

Comment: @jick I'd suggest adding 뷁 as an answer - seems pretty well known?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it would qualify as a real word. :)

Comment: One example of practical value would be 짢, as in 언짢다, which is composed of 5 characters, if you count the double consonant as two.

Comment: 뿶 would definitely be the answer (6 JAMO!!!)
let's count it 뿶 is right

Comment: I know I'm a bit (just a tiny bit) late, but doesn't 짧 have 5 as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Old Hangul (옛한글) apparently allowed up to 9 jamo in a single block.** I am not sure if this was "proper" use or abuse of Hangul at the time... I managed to find a reference to one of these "in the wild:" [ꥸᅦퟗ](https://uncyclopedia.kr/wiki/%EA%A5%B8%E1%85%A6%ED%9F%97) which cites [this document from 1922](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc2/wg2/docs/n3168.pdf#page=28).

Unicode supports Old Hangul, if just to study and document old Korean texts. (Interestingly, the character ꥸᅦퟗ is rendered as a single character in HTML, but appears as three separate characters in the text box while editing.)

---

Some special IME's support Old Hangul input. [Here is an explanation of how 9 jamo can be combined into a single block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/hangul):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that "ㅉㅎㅔㄹㄹㅋ" in the cited document from 1922 is given explicitly as an example of a nonsensical syllable where the author says that the natural rules of consonants and vowels are seriously violated.

Answer (score 5):

This table 
 ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables )
seems to contain some syllable blocks with 5 jamos.

괁 괂

굀 굁 굂 굃

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jamo

<sub>After some searching, I'd tentatively say that 5 is the max. -- that 6 jamos or 6 jamo syllable blocks don't exist.</sub>