# How many different "blocks" can be formed from the letters of the korean alphabet?

Tags: hangul

A block (what Koreans would call a 글자), such as `답`, consists of what I would call three "letters," while `다` consists of two "letters" (what Koreans might call 자모). How many such valid unique blocks are able to be formed from the letters available?

Another way of saying this: How many 글자 are there?

Comment: Welcome to the site. So far according to https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/is-there-a-korean-word-for-syllable-block/2303 we didn't come up with a name for a "block" apart from simply "글자" (character) - I think what you're calling a "letter" can be called a 자모.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables states that the "Hangul Syllables" Unicode block contains 11,172 code points - I'm not sure that's a 'correct' answer to your question but possibly interesting...

Comment: 11,172 is from calculation, but the number of real-used hangul block is roughly 4,000, which includes 1,800 from Hanja. Anyone know the example in 1800 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically, there are 11,172 possible Hangeul syllable blocks (in modern Hangeul).

There are 19 possible initial consonants: ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㄲㄸㅃㅆㅉ

There are 21 possible vowels: ㅏㅐㅑㅒㅓㅔㅕㅖㅗㅘㅙㅚㅛㅜㅝㅞㅟㅠㅡㅢ

There are 28 possible 받침s (syllable endings): empty, ㄱ,ㄲ,ㄳ,ㄴ,ㄵ,ㄶ,ㄷ,ㄹ,ㄺ,ㄻ,ㄼ,ㄽ,ㄾ,ㄿ,ㅀ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅄ,ㅅ,ㅆ,ㅇ,ㅈ,ㅊ,ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅎ

19*21*28=11,172.

All of these are represented in the Unicode block AC00-D7A3.
However, most of these are not found in normal language (syllables like 횚).

Comment: The thing you say there are 28 of-- what is that? I followed the starting consonant and vowel part, but then I lost you.

Comment: @temporary_user_name 28 받침s - that's what the bottom part of the block, the syllable ending, is called in Korean.  Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the old Korean letters unused nowadays into account, and if your “valid” means “possible,” [apparently there're at least 1.6 million possible constructions without tone marks](http://ko.charset.wikia.com/wiki/%EC%9C%A0%EB%8B%88%EC%BD%94%EB%93%9C_%EC%98%9B%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80_1638750%EC%9E%90). Absolutely no idea how to pronounce those blacky runes, though.

```
No. Initial Medial  Final
1   ᄀᅠ 1100 ᅟᅠ 1160 
2   ᄁᅠ 1101 ᅟᅡ 1161 ᅟᅠᆨ 11A8
3   ᅚᅠ 115A ᅟᅶ 1176 ᅟᅠᆩ 11A9
4   ᄂᅠ 1102 ᅟᅷ 1177 ᅟᅠᇺ 11FA
5   ᄓᅠ 1113 ᅟᆣ 11A3 ᅟᅠᇃ 11C3
6   ᄔᅠ 1114 ᅟᅢ 1162 ᅟᅠᇻ 11FB
7   ᄕᅠ 1115 ᅟᅣ 1163 ᅟᅠᆪ 11AA
8   ᄖᅠ 1116 ᅟᅸ 1178 ᅟᅠᇄ 11C4
9   ᅛᅠ 115B ᅟᅹ 1179 ᅟᅠᇼ 11FC
10  ᅜᅠ 115C ᅟᆤ 11A4 ᅟᅠᇽ 11FD
11  ᅝᅠ 115D ᅟᅤ 1164 ᅟᅠᇾ 11FE
12  ᄃᅠ 1103 ᅟᅥ 1165 ᅟᅠᆫ 11AB
13  ᄗᅠ 1117 ᅟᅺ 117A ᅟᅠᇅ 11C5
14  ᄄᅠ 1104 ᅟᅻ 117B ᅟᅠᇿ 11FF
15  ᅞᅠ 115E ᅟᅼ 117C ᅟᅠᇆ 11C6
16  ꥠᅠ A960 ᅟᅦ 1166 ᅟᅠퟋ D7CB
17  ꥡᅠ A961 ᅟᅧ 1167 ᅟᅠᇇ 11C7
18  ꥢᅠ A962 ᅟᆥ 11A5 ᅟᅠᇈ 11C8
19  ꥣᅠ A963 ᅟᅽ 117D ᅟᅠᆬ 11AC
20  ᄅᅠ 1105 ᅟᅾ 117E ᅟᅠퟌ D7CC
21  ꥤᅠ A964 ᅟᅨ 1168 ᅟᅠᇉ 11C9
22  ꥥᅠ A965 ᅟᅩ 1169 ᅟᅠᆭ 11AD
23  ᄘᅠ 1118 ᅟᅪ 116A ᅟᅠᆮ 11AE
24  ꥦᅠ A966 ᅟᅫ 116B ᅟᅠᇊ 11CA
25  ꥧᅠ A967 ᅟᆦ 11A6 ᅟᅠퟍ D7CD
26  ᄙᅠ 1119 ᅟᆧ 11A7 ᅟᅠퟎ D7CE
27  ꥨᅠ A968 ᅟᅿ 117F ᅟᅠᇋ 11CB
28  ꥩᅠ A969 ᅟᆀ 1180 ᅟᅠퟏ D7CF
29  ꥪᅠ A96A ᅟힰ D7B0 ᅟᅠퟐ D7D0
30  ꥫᅠ A96B ᅟᆁ 1181 ᅟᅠퟑ D7D1
31  ꥬᅠ A96C ᅟᆂ 1182 ᅟᅠퟒ D7D2
32  ꥭᅠ A96D ᅟힱ D7B1 ᅟᅠퟓ D7D3
33  ꥮᅠ A96E ᅟᆃ 1183 ᅟᅠퟔ D7D4
34  ᄚᅠ 111A ᅟᅬ 116C ᅟᅠᆯ 11AF
35  ᄛᅠ 111B ᅟᅭ 116D ᅟᅠᆰ 11B0
36  ᄆᅠ 1106 ᅟힲ D7B2 ᅟᅠퟕ D7D5
37  ꥯᅠ A96F ᅟힳ D7B3 ᅟᅠᇌ 11CC
38  ꥰᅠ A970 ᅟᆄ 1184 ᅟᅠퟖ D7D6
39  ᄜᅠ 111C ᅟᆅ 1185 ᅟᅠᇍ 11CD
40  ꥱᅠ A971 ᅟힴ D7B4 ᅟᅠᇎ 11CE
41  ᄝᅠ 111D ᅟᆆ 1186 ᅟᅠᇏ 11CF
42  ᄇᅠ 1107 ᅟᆇ 1187 ᅟᅠᇐ 11D0
43  ᄞᅠ 111E ᅟᆈ 1188 ᅟᅠퟗ D7D7
44  ᄟᅠ 111F ᅟᅮ 116E ᅟᅠᆱ 11B1
45  ᄠᅠ 1120 ᅟᆉ 1189 ᅟᅠᇑ 11D1
46  ᄈᅠ 1108 ᅟᆊ 118A ᅟᅠᇒ 11D2
47  ᄡᅠ 1121 ᅟᅯ 116F ᅟᅠퟘ D7D8
48  ᄢᅠ 1122 ᅟᆋ 118B ᅟᅠᆲ 11B2
49  ᄣᅠ 1123 ᅟᅰ 1170 ᅟᅠퟙ D7D9
50  ᄤᅠ 1124 ᅟힵ D7B5 ᅟᅠᇓ 11D3
51  ᄥᅠ 1125 ᅟᆌ 118C ᅟᅠퟚ D7DA
52  ᄦᅠ 1126 ᅟᆍ 118D ᅟᅠᇔ 11D4
53  ꥲᅠ A972 ᅟᅱ 1171 ᅟᅠᇕ 11D5
54  ᄧᅠ 1127 ᅟힶ D7B6 ᅟᅠᆳ 11B3
55  ᄨᅠ 1128 ᅟᅲ 1172 ᅟᅠᇖ 11D6
56  ꥳᅠ A973 ᅟᆎ 118E ᅟᅠᇗ 11D7
57  ᄩᅠ 1129 ᅟힷ D7B7 ᅟᅠퟛ D7DB
58  ᄪᅠ 112A ᅟᆏ 118F ᅟᅠᇘ 11D8
59  ꥴᅠ A974 ᅟᆐ 1190 ᅟᅠᆴ 11B4
60  ᄫᅠ 112B ᅟᆑ 1191 ᅟᅠᆵ 11B5
61  ᄬᅠ 112C ᅟᆒ 1192 ᅟᅠᆶ 11B6
62  ᄉᅠ 1109 ᅟힸ D7B8 ᅟᅠᇙ 11D9
63  ᄭᅠ 112D ᅟᆓ 1193 ᅟᅠퟜ D7DC
64  ᄮᅠ 112E ᅟᆔ 1194 ᅟᅠퟝ D7DD
65  ᄯᅠ 112F ᅟᅳ 1173 ᅟᅠᆷ 11B7
66  ᄰᅠ 1130 ᅟힹ D7B9 ᅟᅠᇚ 11DA
67  ᄱᅠ 1131 ᅟힺ D7BA ᅟᅠퟞ D7DE
68  ᄲᅠ 1132 ᅟힻ D7BB ᅟᅠퟟ D7DF
69  ᄳᅠ 1133 ᅟힼ D7BC ᅟᅠᇛ 11DB
70  ᄊᅠ 110A ᅟᆕ 1195 ᅟᅠퟠ D7E0
71  ꥵᅠ A975 ᅟᆖ 1196 ᅟᅠᇜ 11DC
72  ᄴᅠ 1134 ᅟᅴ 1174 ᅟᅠퟡ D7E1
73  ᄵᅠ 1135 ᅟᆗ 1197 ᅟᅠᇝ 11DD
74  ᄶᅠ 1136 ᅟᅵ 1175 ᅟᅠᇞ 11DE
75  ᄷᅠ 1137 ᅟᆘ 1198 ᅟᅠᇟ 11DF
76  ᄸᅠ 1138 ᅟᆙ 1199 ᅟᅠퟢ D7E2
77  ᄹᅠ 1139 ᅟힽ D7BD ᅟᅠᇠ 11E0
78  ᄺᅠ 113A ᅟힾ D7BE ᅟᅠᇡ 11E1
79  ᄻᅠ 113B ᅟힿ D7BF ᅟᅠᇢ 11E2
80  ᄼᅠ 113C ᅟퟀ D7C0 ᅟᅠᆸ 11B8
81  ᄽᅠ 113D ᅟᆚ 119A ᅟᅠퟣ D7E3
82  ᄾᅠ 113E ᅟퟁ D7C1 ᅟᅠᇣ 11E3
83  ᄿᅠ 113F ᅟퟂ D7C2 ᅟᅠퟤ D7E4
84  ᅀᅠ 1140 ᅟᆛ 119B ᅟᅠퟥ D7E5
85  ᄋᅠ 110B ᅟퟃ D7C3 ᅟᅠퟦ D7E6
86  ᅁᅠ 1141 ᅟᆜ 119C ᅟᅠᆹ 11B9
87  ᅂᅠ 1142 ᅟퟄ D7C4 ᅟᅠퟧ D7E7
88  ꥶᅠ A976 ᅟᆝ 119D ᅟᅠퟨ D7E8
89  ᅃᅠ 1143 ᅟᆞ 119E ᅟᅠퟩ D7E9
90  ᅄᅠ 1144 ᅟퟅ D7C5 ᅟᅠᇤ 11E4
91  ᅅᅠ 1145 ᅟᆟ 119F ᅟᅠᇥ 11E5
92  ᅆᅠ 1146 ᅟퟆ D7C6 ᅟᅠᇦ 11E6
93  ᅇᅠ 1147 ᅟᆠ 11A0 ᅟᅠᆺ 11BA
94  ᅈᅠ 1148 ᅟᆡ 11A1 ᅟᅠᇧ 11E7
95  ᅉᅠ 1149 ᅟᆢ 11A2 ᅟᅠᇨ 11E8
96  ᅊᅠ 114A         ᅟᅠᇩ 11E9
97  ᅋᅠ 114B         ᅟᅠퟪ D7EA
98  ꥷᅠ A977         ᅟᅠᇪ 11EA
99  ᅌᅠ 114C         ᅟᅠퟫ D7EB
100 ᄌᅠ 110C         ᅟᅠᆻ 11BB
101 ᅍᅠ 114D         ᅟᅠퟬ D7EC
102 ᄍᅠ 110D         ᅟᅠퟭ D7ED
103 ꥸᅠ A978         ᅟᅠퟮ D7EE
104 ᅎᅠ 114E         ᅟᅠퟯ D7EF
105 ᅏᅠ 114F         ᅟᅠퟰ D7F0
106 ᅐᅠ 1150         ᅟᅠퟱ D7F1
107 ᅑᅠ 1151         ᅟᅠퟲ D7F2
108 ᄎᅠ 110E         ᅟᅠᇫ 11EB
109 ᅒᅠ 1152         ᅟᅠퟳ D7F3
110 ᅓᅠ 1153         ᅟᅠퟴ D7F4
111 ᅔᅠ 1154         ᅟᅠᆼ 11BC
112 ᅕᅠ 1155         ᅟᅠᇰ 11F0
113 ᄏᅠ 110F         ᅟᅠᇬ 11EC
114 ᄐᅠ 1110         ᅟᅠᇭ 11ED
115 ꥹᅠ A979         ᅟᅠퟵ D7F5
116 ᄑᅠ 1111         ᅟᅠᇱ 11F1
117 ᅖᅠ 1156         ᅟᅠᇲ 11F2
118 ꥺᅠ A97A         ᅟᅠᇮ 11EE
119 ᅗᅠ 1157         ᅟᅠᇯ 11EF
120 ᄒᅠ 1112         ᅟᅠퟶ D7F6
121 ꥻᅠ A97B         ᅟᅠᆽ 11BD
122 ᅘᅠ 1158         ᅟᅠퟷ D7F7
123 ᅙᅠ 1159         ᅟᅠퟸ D7F8
124 ꥼᅠ A97C         ᅟᅠퟹ D7F9
125 ᅟᅠ 115F         ᅟᅠᆾ 11BE
126                 ᅟᅠᆿ 11BF
127                 ᅟᅠᇀ 11C0
128                 ᅟᅠᇁ 11C1
129                 ᅟᅠᇳ 11F3
130                 ᅟᅠퟺ D7FA
131                 ᅟᅠퟻ D7FB
132                 ᅟᅠᇴ 11F4
133                 ᅟᅠᇂ 11C2
134                 ᅟᅠᇵ 11F5
135                 ᅟᅠᇶ 11F6
136                 ᅟᅠᇷ 11F7
137                 ᅟᅠᇸ 11F8
138                 ᅟᅠᇹ 11F9
```

> ## ᄿᆓᇜ​ꥨᅵᇸ​ꥩᆖᇰ​ꥤힸퟹ​ᅂힾᇠ​ꥺᆐᆱ​ᄩᅯퟮ​ᄳퟂᇲ​​ꥸᅸᇜ​ᄹᆖퟝ​ᄴᆚퟟᄬힼᆩ​ᄱᆠᇞ​ᄏᆝᇊ​ꥰᅺퟕ​ᄍᆢᇒ​ᄱᆆᇌ​ᄷᆔᇵ​ᄆᆁᇄ​ᄭᅧퟹ​
>
> ꥹᆃퟘ​똬ᇖ​ᄻᆚᇽ​ᄄᅾퟥ​ᅚᆚᇐ​ᅛힷퟨ​ᅛퟅᇩ​ᄦᆄᆾ​ᅍᆥퟚ​ᅍힺᇆ​ꥩힲퟡ​ᅛᅢᇋ​ꥵᅦᆲ​ᄢퟆᇑ​ꥡᆣퟣ​됴ퟘ​ᅂퟀᇀ​ᄜᅠᇚ​ᄊᆌᇤ​ᅊᆔᇑ​ᄀᅻᇪ​ᅊᆔᇯ​ᄃᆈᇛ​ꥣힰᇲ​ᄄힻᆮ​뙤ퟍ​ꥨᆍᇌ​ᄩᅵퟨ​ᄺᅮퟨ​ᄔᅠᇡ​ᄷᆟퟋ​ᄵퟄퟗ​ᄧᆏᆵ​ᄬힼᆩ​ᄱᆠᇞ​ᄏᆝᇊ​ꥰᅺퟕ​ᄍᆢᇒ​ᄱᆆᇌ​ᄷᆔᇵ​ᄆᆁᇄ​ᄭᅧퟹ​ᅍᆄᇿ​ꥻᅠᇍ​ᄐᅻퟦ​ᅕᅣퟪ​ᄮᅵퟋ​ᄉᆚᆨ​ᄯᆒᆰ​ꥠᆆᇿ​ᅊᅰᇼ​ᄈힰퟙ​ᅂᆈᆸ​ᄭᅮᇽ​ꥭᆣᇳ​ᄯᆉᇲ​ᄔힵퟧ​ꥨᅷᇡ​ꥶᅠᇯ​ꥱᆋퟨ​ᄭퟂᇆ​ᄯᆓᆫ​ꥣힹᇛ​ᅌᅡퟦ​ᄵᆡᇢ​ᄍᆗퟶ​ᅚᅠᆰ​ᄯᅨᇄ​ᄵᆜퟔ​ᄅퟆᇌ​ᅈᆚᇪ​ᅁᅾᇷ​ᄞᆃᇛ​ᄣᆐᇫ​ᄎힶퟯ​ᄤᅬᇎ​ᄐힱퟞ​ᄝᆐퟜ​ᄌᆧퟑ​ꥪᅬᇳ​ꥨힲᆬ​ꥪힸᇅ​ᄟᆐᆹ​ꥬힴᇪ​ᄌᆧᇟ​헤ᇉ​ꥮᅺᇄ​ᄿힽᇆ​ᅍᆟᇣ​ꥴퟆᆴ​ꥢᅻퟻ​ᄑᆗᇓ​ᄪᅱᇍ​ᅖퟄᇤ​ᄁᆞᇊ​쁘ᇕ​ᄒᆙᇚ​ᅄᅲᆩ​ᄍힱᇛ​ꥢᆈᇧ​ᄊힴퟦ​ᄻᅲퟓ​ꥶᆂᆿ​ᅀퟀᇿ​ᅀᆞᇪ​ᄯᆐᆨ​ᅒퟂᇜ​ᄦᆗᆵ​ᅍힸᇼ​ᅘᆗퟰ​ᄰᅥᇭ​ᅀퟄᇇ​ᄙᆚᇶ​ᄗᆌᇛ​ᅞᆞᇰ​ᅖᆞᇡ​ᅈᅽᆾ​ꥦᅰퟮ​ᄃᆥᇽ​ᄇᆏퟓ​ᄹᅪퟒ​ᄼힼᇴ​ꥱᆎᇩ​ᄕᆥᇶ​ᄥᆅᆹ​뮈ᇚ​ᅕퟅퟧ​ꥠᅨᇉ​ꥸᅸᇜ​ᄹᆖퟝ​ᄴᆚퟟ​ᅔᆄퟥ​ꥸퟆퟫ​ᅗᅼퟜ​ᄥힽᆽ​ᄉᆏᇯ​ᄂퟅᇓ​ᅋᅤᇄ​ᅂᅱᇭ​ᅝᅳퟭ​ᅌퟀퟢ​ᄉᆝᇰ​ꥳힵᇿ​ꥱᆉᆩ​ᄰᆇᇢ​ᅝᅳᇊ​ᄍퟃᆻ​ꥬᅬᇝ​ᄁퟂᇍ​ᅒᆉퟵ​ᄬퟁᇆ​ᄯᆅᇰ​ᄊힹퟏ​ᄜᅺᇻ​ꥨᅣᇬ​ᄏᅽퟕ​ᄩힽᇻ​ᅀᆗᇩ​ꥲᅠᇔ​ꥻힰᇋ​ꥧᆌᇡ​쨰ᇺ​ᄞퟀퟤ​며ퟰ​ᅎᆒᇐ​ꥳᅡᇸ​ᄞᅲퟷ​ᄏᅠᆲ​ᄛᅴᇥ​ᄰᆛᆻ​ꥶᅽퟲ​ᄴᅶퟬ​ᄁᆞᇡ​ᄭᆇᇓ​ᄰᆘᆺ​ᄹᆒᆹ​ᅁᅬᆯ​ꥣힰᇳ​ꥩᅳퟳ​ꥦퟆᆳ​ᄃᆚᆺ​ᄺᆑᇀ​ᄲힸퟲ​ᅏᆗퟦ​ꥯᆜᇈ​ᅆᅪᇽ​ꥷᆝᆯ​ᅈᆞᇮ​ᅜᅧퟖ​ꥵᆌퟷ​ᄣᆑᆿ​ᅙᅥᇠ​ꥺퟂퟋ​툯​ꥤᅹퟌ​ꥱᅿᆰ​ᄱᅱퟑ​ᄿퟀᆪ​ᄢᅶퟌ​ᄀᅻᇇ​ᅆᆚퟞ​ꥷᆧᆪ​ᄱᆐᆰ​ᅓퟃᇰ​ᅉힳퟮ​ꥦᅨᆮ​ꥼᆠᇙ​ꥻᅬᇧ​ᄚힸᆭ​ᄉᆆᇥ​ᅂퟁퟰ​ᄅᆍᇬ​ᄮᆑퟷ​ꥹᆝퟚ​ᅜᅹᆾ​ᄶᆘᇶ​ꥣힲퟞ​ꥼᆕᇰ​캁​ꥬᆤퟻ​ᄢᆊퟘ​ꥴᆚퟧ​ᅔᆕퟮ​ᄏᆉᇇ​ᅃᅬᇈ​ᅇᅱퟶ​ꥫힵퟥ​ꥮᆗퟫ​ᄻᆃퟴ​ᄱᆑᇄ​ᄘᅭᇤ​ᅂힾᆬ​ᅌힱᇚ​ᄇᅻᇱ​ᅘᆥᆾ​ᄠᅺᆮ​퓌ᇺ​ᄧힲᆻ​ᄿᆍᇸ​ᅄᆔᇝ​ᄦᅬᇶ​ꥬퟆᆶ​ꥢힶᆽ​ᄡힶᇢ​ᅎᆈퟠ​ꥦힿᇴ​ᄹힺᇑ​ᅐힳᆪ​ᅗᆝᆽ​ᅗힷᇵ​ᅞᅮᇟ​ꥴᆌퟝ​ᄝᆄᆽ​ᄑᆧퟖ​ᅁᆓퟍ​ꥡᅷᆮ​ᅄퟁᇴ​ᅌᆌᇙ​ꥴᆌᇧ​ᄶힷᇆ​ᄝᆊᇢ​ꥧᅣᆱ​ᄬᅠᇍ​ꥭᆜᇖ​ᅁᆤᆬ​ꥺᆙᆼ​ᄟힱퟡ​ᅇힵퟙ​ᅐᅣᇇ​ꥵᅤퟍ​ᄧᆌퟏ​ꥫᆋᆰ​ᄘힻퟞ​ᄚᅭퟙ​ᅗᅤᇁ​ᅆힵퟵ​ᅙᅵᇺ​ᄱᅴᇣ​ᄋힺᇎ​ꥣퟂᆮ​ᅌힸퟫ​ᄧᆈᇯ​ᅓퟃᇠ​ᅔᆐᇨ​ᄯᆑᇨ​ꥷퟃᆻ​ᅁᆚퟺ​ᄿힱퟵ​ᄞᆛᇗ​ꥨힰᆸ​ᄴᅺᇒ​ᅉힲᇋ​ᄿᅧᇱ​ꥵᅸᇬ​ᄫᅬᇉ​ꥥᅫᇙ​ᅆᅸퟙ​ᄡᅤퟻ​ᅘᆕퟜ​ᄂᆡퟔ​ꥭᆌ​애ퟥ​ᄔퟃᆪ​ᄟᅶᇯ​ᄨᆣᇱ​ᄅᆅᆪ​ᄩힱᇸ​ꥷힴᇷ​ᅒᆆᇝ​ᄇᆕퟯ​ᄷퟄᆰ​ꥥᅯퟋ​ᄾᅵퟠ​ꥰힵᆬ​ᅗᆠᇝ​쵸ᇵ​ᄛힺᆽ​ꥳᅽퟪ​ᄟᅮᇑ​ꥭᆝᇟ​ᄭᆧᆰ​ᅐힵퟩ​ꥰᅥퟸ​ꥷᆒퟍ​ᄂힵퟱ​ꥶᆧᇦ​ᄤᅨퟒ​ᅚᆛᇜ​ᄿᆓᇜ​ꥨᅵᇸ​ꥩᆖᇰ​ꥤힸퟹ​ᅂힾᇠ​ꥺᆐᆱ​ᄩᅯퟮ​ᄳퟂᇲ​ꥫᅧퟠ​ᅔᆞᇞ​ᅑᅽퟧ​ᄚᅴᇨ​ᅙힴퟘ​ᄣᆟퟶ​ᄄᆋᆴ​ꥹᅣᇰ​ᄙᅶퟶ​ᄿힹᇮ​ᄛힵᆷ​ꥭᆊᇟ​ꥯힵퟋ​ᄺᅭᆯ​ᄫᆚퟯ​ᄘힴퟶ​ᅀힳᇛ​ᄰᅫᇫ​ᅓᆊퟷ​ꥭힵ​ᄘힳᇭ​최ퟚ​ᄠퟃퟏ​ᅑᆗᇯ​ᄡᅤᇪ​ᄃᆡᇔ​ᄏᆇퟙ​ꥦퟅퟚ​ᅄᅷᆱ​ᄦힷퟱ​ᄔᅿᇌ​ᄶᆤᆴ​ᄁᆕퟮ​ᄎᆁퟭ​ꥨᆕᇺ​ᄭᅷퟱ​ᄊힴᇅ​ᅟᆝᇁ​ᄺᆍᇂ​ᄿᆚퟱ​ꥬᆜᇇ​ᅁퟅᇋ​ꥹힺퟷ​ᄴퟀᇒ​ꥨힸᇴ​ꥢힸퟺ​ᄐힷᇂ​ᅉᆐᇤ​ᅒힲᆲ​ᅆힰᇫ​ꥯᆅᇞ​ᄷᆦᇥ​ᄱᅾᇄ​ᄒퟃퟕ​ᄇᆧퟝ​ᄧᆉퟸ​ᄭᅥퟲ​ᄚᅿퟸ​ꥧᅥᇧ​ᄺᆋᇵ​ꥱᆧퟷ​줘ퟸ​ᅟힼᆭ​ꥤᆉᆺ​ᅙᆟᇻ​ᄄᆋᆪ​ᄬᅿᇖ​ᅝᆊᇧ​ꥭᆉᆰ​ᄝᅷᆲ​ꥨᆀᆩ​ꥣᅦᇉ​ᄚᅼᇼ​ꥷᆝퟩ​ᄋᆂᇓ​ꥰퟁᇆ​ᄇᆔᇱ​ᅞힼퟷ​ᅔᆆᇐ​ᄓힷᇨ​ᄰᆀᇷ​ᅞힸᆴ​ᄼᅨᇼ​ꥮᅵᆴ​ᄲᅵᇵ​ᄺᆕᆼ​ᄻᆔᇵ​ꥹᆀퟩ​ᄏힷᇤ​ᄓᅬퟓ​ᄂᆢퟶ​ᄫힾퟘ​ᅗᆁᇫ​ꥣퟄᆱ​ᅞᆅᇃ​ᄘᅡᇔ​ᄗᆃᇙ​ᄖᅳᇑ​ᅍᆜퟳ​ꥼᅾᆳ​ᄢᆒퟐ​ꥷᅩᇬ​ᄖᆦᆲ​ᄦᆙᆨ​ᄭᆢퟱ​ꥷퟃퟹ​ᄁᆍᇅ​ꥮᅴᇮ​ᅕᅻퟙ​ᄾᆖᆳ​ᅁᅬퟥ​ᄭᅫᇝ​ᄨᅯퟐ​ꥧᆗᇭ​ᄺᆎퟙ​ᄈᆌᇖ​ᅎힷᇩ​ᄙᆣퟌ​ꥢᆖᇪ​ᄥᅭᇒ​ᄯᆟᆻ​ᅙᅧᇅ​ᄘᅠᆳ​ᄞᆁᇖ​ᄦᅱퟦ​ᄆᆝᇠ​ꥰᆗᇈ​ᄦퟅᇝ​ᄺힴᇨ​ᄛᅣᇵ​ꥷힷᇚ​ꥹᆎퟻ​ᄝᆍᇩ​ᄋힳᇆ​ᄼᅽᇨ​ᄧᆋퟦ​ᅞᅷᇺ​ᄆힲᆭ​ᄀᆅᇔ​ᄒᆌᇂ​ᄒᆟᆼ​ᄒᅼᇰ​ᄬᆞퟹ​ꥩힳᆹ​ᄪᆡᇠ​ᅑᆊᇘ​ꥡᅭퟷ​ᅐᆍᇘ​ᅛᅧᆭ​ᅏᅺퟪ​ᅁᆇᆴ​ᅉퟅᇎ​ᄽᅺᇓ​ᅀᆐᇱ​ᅛᆞퟛ​ᄘힹᇢ​ᅍᆂᇶ​ᅅퟂᇇ​ꥮᅢᇾ​ꥲᅸᆿ​ᅖힸퟏ​ᄦᅯᇻ​ꥱᆞퟨ​ᅒᆓᇸ​ᅕퟂퟪ​ꥷힱᇝ​ᄡᅵᇆ​ᄵힺퟮ​ᅕᅻᆳ​ᅚᆃퟶ​ᄨᆔᇓ​ᄔힺퟒ​ᅕᆀퟢ​ᅂᆜퟒ​ᄩᆛᆷ​ꥯힱᇽ​ᅋힲᇡ​ᄟᆎᇺ​ꥩᆇᆪ​ꥨᆒᇈ​ᄻᆌퟘ​ꥸᆓퟣ​ᅉퟄퟏ​ᅏᆘퟥ​ꥹᅺퟘ​ᄀᆍ​ꥹᆀᇡ​ꥡᆞᇔ​ꥸᆘᇗ​캦​ᄺᅦퟕ​ᅖᅭᆫ​ᅏퟅᆾ​ᅇힵᆪ​ꥦᅭᇠ​ꥸᅩᇼ​ᄍᆅᇊ​ᄛퟁᇯ​ꥺᆅᇄ​ᄪᆇퟕ​ᄶᅷퟌ​ᅁᆍퟟ​ᅟᅪᇕ​ᄬᆈᆯ​ꥦᅶᇵ​ᄖᆁퟗ​ꥺᅣퟫ​ᅎᆑᆯ​ᄳᅨᇇ​ᄞힳᇻ​ᄄퟂᇁ​ᅀᆏퟌ​ᅀힲᇡ​ᄙힰퟸ​ꥧᅻᇺ​ꥥᆧᇛ​ꥰᆢퟐ​ꥶᅵᇷ​ꥩힿᆻ​ꥦퟂᇮ​ᅟᅵᇔ​ᄗᆆᇾ​ᄦᅠᇇ​ꥧᆆᇞ​ᄀힾퟎ​ᅝퟄᇎ​ᅃᅫᇹ​ᅐᆖퟲ​ᅈᅷퟦ​ꥷᆝᆷ​ᅐᅿᆸ​ᅜퟂᇑ​ᄱᅬᇜ​ᅉᆈퟚ​ᄺᆡᇀ​ꥹᅬᇡ​ᄍᅺᇩ​ꥳᆌᆱ​ᅚힸퟸ​ᅊᆔퟥ​ᄽᅹᇂ​ᅊힲퟰ​ᄳힷᆲ​ᄅᆘퟘ​ꥭᆃᇖ​ᄣᆌᇺ​ꥻᆖᆺ​ᅈᆇᇯ​ᄢᆃᇱ​ᅘힳퟦ​ᅜᅪᇴ​ᄉힲᆭ​ᄈᆉᇤ​ᄐᆎᆭ​ꥤᅿᇅ​ᅙᆋퟋ​ᅏᆢퟡ​ᄨᆑᆴ​ᄚᅨᆲ​ᄙퟀᇈ​ꥹᅤퟵ​ꥳퟁퟲ​ᅃᆀᇯ​ᅗힶᇒ​ꥴᅧᇩ​ꥮᅸퟋ​ᅟᆃᆰ​ᅋᆂᇐ​ᄑᆈᇭ​ᄓᆜퟎ​ᄟᅱퟴ​ᄠᆞퟲ​ᅋᅭᇋ​꽤ퟶ​ꥧᅥᇨ​ᄝᆂᆿ​ᄏᅶᇁ​ᄱퟂퟚ​ᅄᆄᇀ​ᄯᆗᇶ​내ᇖ​ꥠힼᇘ​ꥻᅣᇯ​ᅗᅤᇤ​ᅈힻᆽ​ᅏힹퟤ​ᄝퟄᇌ​ᄰᅡᇥ​ᄊᅻᇐ​ᄿᆃᇌ​ᄻᆀퟕ​ᄽힲᇁ​ᄄᅹퟯ​ᄱᆈퟹ​ᄝᆆᇃ​ᄷힺퟨ​ᄈᅺᇣ​ᄟᅨퟠ​ꥹᅮᇘ​ᄆퟁᆷ​ᄋᆕᆬ​ꥨힾᇾ​ᄦᅣퟤ​뵤ᇖ​ᅎᆐᇷ​ᄗᆃᇳ​ᅐᅯퟙ​ꥪᅺᇾ​ᄦᆑᆭ